# Setting a Storyboard Tab Controller, More Tab's Navigation Bar Colour

Tags: objective-c, ios, storyboard, uinavigationbar

So throughout my application I implement `Navigation Bars` with the style Black Opaque.

**The Problem**

I can't seem to set the colour of the `Navigation Bar` that presents itself when the user selects the automatically generated `More Tab`

**The Question**

How do I set the colour of this Navigation Bar to Black Opaque?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: How are you setting up your toolbars?

Comment: @Dustin do you mean my NavigationBars or TabBars? My TabBarController is all done via storyboard and therefore the More tab is auto generated by the storyboard

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, I'm one of those sad people who is now answering their own question :P Hopefully it helps..

So you need to get a reference to the `TabBarController` in your app delegate and then change the style of the more navigation controller from there. The code below shows you how and where..

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    // Override point for customization after application launch.
    UITabBarController *_tabController = (UITabBarController*)_window.rootViewController;
    _tabController.moreNavigationController.navigationBar.barStyle = UIBarStyleBlackOpaque;
    return YES;
}
```